# In the process of probability of two flavor neutrino, how does the factor $1.27$ comes from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

Up so far I have been working on deriving probability for two flavor neutrino 
and have consistent results with wikipedia or textbook.

But I have some trouble with deriving some factor $1.27$.

\begin{align}
  P(\nu_\alpha \rightarrow \nu_\beta) &= \sin^2(2\theta) \sin^2 \left( \frac{\Delta m_{12}^2 L}{4 E_\nu} \right)  \\
  &= \sin^2(2\theta) \sin^2\left( 1.27 \frac{\Delta m_{12}^2(eV^2) L(km)}{ E_\nu(GeV)} \right)
\end{align}
Since usual mass is denoted as $\frac{M(G)eV}{c^2}$ i guess $\frac{1}{c^4}$ is needed but still I couldn't obtain 1.27

Am I missing other constants? it seems to me $\hbar$ should be somewhere , but I don't know where. If $\hbar$ exists, then it seems in the parenthesis, the factor does not dimensionless....

Basically I want to restore all the fundamental constant $\hbar$, $c$ in the parenthesis.  How one restore its fundamental constant from usual quantum field theory computation? Any idea will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: [see WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F4)(1+eV)%5E2+(1km)%2F(1+GeV))

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, i don't get it. It just give the number 1/4,  it still did not give 1.27. The problem here (i think)is not express usual unit into mks unit, but recover the fundamental constants like $\hbar$, $c$.

Comment: did you click on the link? the number 1.27 is disguised as 1.266933... but it is right there :-/

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, Ah Now i see the point for your comment. I need $\hbar c$. Thanks

Comment: That's it :-) Cheers.